# Pressing the device's back button do we have to close the Message box and cancel the backwards navigation too in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In the Certification guidelines 5.2.4 C they mentioned that if the current page displays a context menu or a dialog, the pressing of the Back button must close the menu or dialog and cancel the backward navigation to the previous page.
Is this applicable for MessageBox also?
I am using MessageBox to prompt the user to allow the location service api to use location i.e. lat and long which is in application launching.
Do I have to follow the 5.2.4 C for the MessageBox too be closed and stop back navigation.
Please guide me for standard way to implement so not to fail in Windows phone 7 Certification process.

Answer (score 2):

*4.Check the Back button Twice:*

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress( System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )  
{      
    if (DemoPopup.isOpen)
    {
     e.Cancel = true;

      //hide the popup
     DemoPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
    else
    {
     base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a Message Box displayed (or a Context Menu) then pressing the back button should dismiss the Message Box instead of navigating backwards, i.e. backwards navigation should not occur.

However, in the case of `MessageBox.Show` and `ContextMenu` (from the Silverlight Toolkit), I think this happens for you automatically.